# Como combinar dos "for i " en bash

Tags: linux, bucle-for, bash

Tengo este comando :

```
find . -type f|xargs wc -l|sort -r|cut -f1,2 -d'.'|tail +2

  62 ./4

  31 ./41

  22 ./3

  17 ./1
```

Que me saca las lineas y el nombre de los archivos.
Ahora lo que quiero hacer es un script que me saque lo mismo pero asi:

```
Nombre: ./4 
Contiene: 62 líneas.
Nombre: ./41 
Contiene: 31 líneas.
Nombre: ./3 
Contiene: 22 líneas.
```

Y he intentado hacer un script pero no consigo combinar los dos for i.Gracias

El codigo del script(intento):

```
#!/bin/bash

r=$(find . -type f|xargs wc -l|sort -r|cut -f1 -d'.'|tail +2)

rr=$(find . -type f|xargs wc -l|sort -r|cut -f2 -d'.'|tail +2)

for i in $rr $r

do

echo   linea $i  archivo $i

done
```

Lo que me saca:

linea /4 archivo /4

linea /41 archivo /41

linea /3 archivo /3

linea /1 archivo /1

linea /8 archivo /8

linea /2 archivo /2

linea /9 archivo /9

linea /81 archivo /81

linea /misej archivo /misej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la otra respuesta y la misma pregunta están usando muchos comandos a mi parecer.

También puedes intentar sacándole jugo a los delimitadores y al mismo `awk`:

```bash
find . -type f \
  | xargs -n1 awk 'END{printf "Nombre: %s|Contiene: %s lineas\n", FILENAME, NR}' \
  | sort -rnt ":" -k3 \
  | xargs -n1 -d "|"
```

El pipeline se divide en 4 etapas:

1. Extracción, con `find`.
2. Enriquecimiento, con `xargs` y `awk` para imprimir tanto el nombre del archivo como la cantidad de líneas usando la plantilla `Nombre %s|Contiene: %s lineas\n`
3. Ordenamiento de mayor a menor según el número en la plantilla en la posición 3
4. Impresión, donde `xargs` usa como delimitador de registro el caracter "|" de la plantilla.

La ejecución nos da como resultado:

```
find . -type f \
  | xargs -n1 awk 'END{printf "Nombre: %s|Contiene: %s lineas\n", FILENAME, NR}' \
  | sort -rnt ":" -k3 \
  | xargs -n1 -d "|"

Nombre: ./veinte
Contiene: 20 lineas
Nombre: ./quince
Contiene: 15 lineas
Nombre: ./diez
Contiene: 10 lineas
Nombre: ./cuatro
Contiene: 4 lineas
```

Answer (score 1):

Mejor que uses [awk](https://www.um.es/innova/OCW/informatica-para-universitarios/ipu_docs/la_shell/awk.pdf) en este caso, de este modo:

```
find . -type f|xargs wc -l|sort -r|cut -f1,2 -d'.'|tail +2 | awk '{print "Nombre: "$2"\nContiene: "$1" líneas"}'
```

donde:

```
{print "Nombre: "$2"\nContiene: "$1" lineas"}
```

ordena imprimir a la salida el texto `Nombre:` , seguido del segundo valor delimitado por espacios que recibe en cada línea de la salida del comando anterior, representado por `$2` y luego le concatenamos un string que contiene un salto de línea `\n` junto con la cadena `Contiene:` , a la cual ahora le concatenamos el primer valor delimitado por espacios, representado por `$1` y finalmente le concatenamos la cadena  `lineas`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió!